# File descriptors of executable binary file and shared libraries in /proc/PID/fd?

Tags: files, linux-kernel, c, file-descriptors

Do user processes keep a file descriptor for the executable file itself, and for shared libraries? For example, if I look into `/proc/PID/fd` of `bash`, I expected to see at least the following `fd`s, besides `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`:

1. one for `/usr/bin/bash`
2. one for `/usr/lib/XXX/libc-2.XX.so` file.

According to kernel function [`load_elf_binary`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L684), it does seem to be the case that a `fd` is allocated for the executable at least.

However, in reality I didn't find such `fd`s in `/proc/PID/fd` folder, likely because they do not exist in `task_struct->files->fd_array`. So the questions are:

1. does kernel store pointers to the `file` objects that corresponds to the executable, and the shared libraries, in a per process struct such as `task_struct`/`thread_info`?
2. if so, which struct?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not file descriptors for those things in general. However, there is `/proc/PID/exe` that shows you what binary is running, and `/proc/PID/maps` and `/proc/PID/map_files/` that shows you what's mapped where. Also, even if these things didn't exist, the kernel can still keep track of it. Not everything in the kernel's memory is exposed via `/proc`.